# Lazysizes fails at lazy loading background images

Tags: javascript, html, performance, lazy-loading

I use [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) library for the lazy loading of images. A span holds the actual image src and an `img` tag is kept in the page source for better SEO.

The `img` is working well that `src="/resources/FolderIMAGES/795_t.JPG"` is correctly added when visible to the user, but adding the event listener  for background images put onto `span` elements fires the loading of all images even if those are not visible to the user...

Some people on lazysizes repository issue hub said in a comment that it is the normal behavior for `lazybeforeunveil` event which fires even when the image is not visible.

So my question is, what is the correct event to detect when an image gets  visible and how should I pass the `data-bg` attribute value to fill the `backgroundImage` style property ? Given the documentation says that `lazybeforeunveil` should be used to handle background images lazyload.

I don't know if it influences anything but the img had `display: none` and changed to `height: 0px !important;width: 0px !important;` so that lazysizes could detect the images.

```
document.addEventListener('lazybeforeunveil', function(e){
    var bg = e.target.getAttribute('data-bg');
    if(bg){
        e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')';
    } });

<img itemprop="image" class=" lazyloaded" data-src="/resources/FolderIMAGES/795_t.JPG" title="Anel Magnético G2 - Wizard Pk Ring" alt="Anel Magnético G2 - Wizard Pk Ring" >

<span class="image lazyloaded" data-bg="/resources/FolderIMAGES/795_t.JPG  " alt="Anel Magnético G2 - Wizard Pk Ring" title="Anel Magnético G2 - Wizard Pk Ring"></span>
```

Comment: I just encountered this issue. I wonder if this is something related to the library or browser.